# Proof limit of non-monotonous sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence 
$b_n= (-1)^n-n$

How can I prove by definition that $lim\ b_n = -\infty$ ?

I know that for an odd $n$ (which also means even $n+1$) you have $b_{n+1}-b_n=(-1)^{n+1}-(n+1)\ -\ ((-1)^n - n) = 1 - n - 1 - (-1) + n = 1 - 1 + 1 - n + n = \ 1$

and that for an even $n$ (which also means odd $n+1$) you have $b_{n+1}-b_n=(-1)^{n+1}-(n+1)\ -\ ((-1)^n - n) = -1 - n - 1 - (1) + n = -1 - 1 - 1 - n + n = \ -3$

Therefore the sequence decreases more between even values of $n$ than it increases  with odd values of $n$. However, how do we set this up by the definition of a limit?

When you start by definition it looks like for any $ L>0, n \geq p \Rightarrow b_n < -L $, therefore we should have

$ (-1)^n - n <- L \ \Leftrightarrow \ -n< - L -(-1)^n \Leftrightarrow \ n > L + (-1)^n$

Then what do we do? Can we say something like 
$ n > L - 1 \ \bigwedge \ n > L + 1 $ and then we get $ n > L + 1 $ and it is done? Is this valid? I would say it is not enough but I cannot get further from here. Please help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the comparison theorem: $b_n \leq 1 - n$ for every $n$. In other words, for every $L> 0$ you have $b_n \leq 1-n \leq -L$ for every $n \geq 1+L$.

Comment: We can say that $b_n\to-\infty$ if for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$, there existst an index $n_r\in\mathbb{N}$, so that $b_n < r$ for any $n>n_r$

Suppose we are given some $r$, can you say after which index all $b_n<r$?